# NextJs multiple params route setup

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, next.js

Does anyone know how to setup their file structure in Nextjs to handle multiple URL params?

My URL is:       `/api/upload?file=${filename}&fileType=${fileType}`

My file structure is:

```
app 
   api
      upload
            [filename]
                      [fileType]
                                route.ts
```

It's my understanding that this is what the directory should look like but I'm getting the following error:

```
- error No HTTP methods exported in 'C:\Users\Alex\Documents\GitHub\procore-new\app\api\upload\route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.
```

Here's my route code:

```
import S3 from "aws-sdk/clients/s3";

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

interface IParams {
  filename: string;
  fileType: string;
}

export async function GET(request: Request, { params }: { params: IParams }) {
  const { filename, fileType } = params;

  const s3 = new S3({
    signatureVersion: "v4",
    region: "us-east-2",
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
  });

  const preSignedUrl = await s3.getSignedUrl("putObject", {
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: filename,
    ContentType: fileType,
    Expires: 5 * 60,
  });

  return NextResponse.json({ preSignedUrl });
}
```

And my frontend request:

```
"use client";

import axios from "axios";

import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";

const ImageUpload = () => {
  const uploadPhoto = async (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const file = e.target.files?.[0]!;
    const filename = file.name;
    const fileType = file.type;

    console.log(file, filename, fileType);
    const res = await axios(
      `/api/upload?file=${filename}&fileType=${fileType}`
    );
    const { url } = await res.data;

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": fileType,
      },
    };

    const upload = await axios.put(url, file, config);
    if (upload.status === 200) {
      console.log("Uploaded successfully!");
    } else {
      console.error("Upload failed.");
    }

    const s3FileUrl = `https://<nextjspractice>.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/${filename}`;
    console.log("file url: ", s3FileUrl);
  };

  return (
    <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" onChange={uploadPhoto} />
  );
};

export default ImageUpload;
```

I'm thinking maybe using the spread operator on the folder? maybe like [...params] but I'm not sure, any help would be amazing!

Comment: just /app/api/upload/route.ts because you don't count the things in query strings

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

If you're using [*paramName*] for your file structure in your app/(route)/route.ts and you have multiple params, you can do the following:

Create a folder spreading the params object, in my case: [...params] and inside create the standard route.ts file.

Then in that file, deconstruct the params like so:

```
interface IParams {
  filename: string;
  fileType: string;
}

export async function GET(request: Request, { params }: { params: IParams }) {
  const { filename, fileType } = params;
```

This'll give you an array of all the params, which for me looked like this:

```
{ params: [ 'PeapodXTraceOne.png', 'image', 'png' ] }
```

Also, in your request to your api, make sure your request looks like so:

```
const res = await axios(`/api/upload/${filename}/${fileType}`);
```

Where each param following the route name has a preceding '/'